# How do I know if files have been copied from my phone to a laptop via USB. Knowing I gave permission for file transfer

Tags: security, usb, privacy, file-transfer

I connected my phone to someone's laptop so they could give me a certain file but I'm suspecting they used the opportunity to copy files from my phone to their device. Is there any chance a log is stored containing  any info about the process and what files were accessed?

Thank you.

Comment: Android only had `logcat` logging buffer a cyclic buffer of configurable size so old entries are overwritten after a certain time. But I am not aware that MTP transfers are logged into logcat. Next time use Bluetooth to receive a file...